# Documenting Packet Loss on Corporate Network

Tags: network

If you suspected intermittent packet loss on a corporate network that you have no authority over, as an IT guy how would you irrefutably document it?  (you are on a Mac, so any *nix toolchain is possible).

Thanks

Comment: This might be better on ServerFault

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the topology of the network.

You can set off different sized pings to different hosts internally and externally, reset these every hour with a bash script, and copy the output to an hourly directory.

Analyse the output in excel, tweak via vim.

You may also try `traceroute -I` which will give you hops using ICMP echo instead of UDP.